# Can't I use Polymer.js via CDN in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add frameworks like AngularJS, Bootstrap and polymer JS into my rails app. Problem with the gems is they are unstable with new versions and they even stop developing gems(which leads to failing of one gem which depends on another)

So I just want to add those frameworks directly into the application root html file via CDN(offered by the vendor). Is that a good practice? Will it cause any future problems in production environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using reliable CDN's (and those offered my vendors can be treat as one) it may **even bring you some improvements** in the production enviromnent, e.g.:

- those assets will be often already cached on your user's machines
- it circumvents browsers limit the number of concurrent connections from the same domain (as your app)

On the flip side, on your dev enviromnent you'll have to wait a liiitle bit more for the website to load those assets comparing it to loading them from localhost ;)

Comment: Does this apply to rails app. Then why people add third party gems instead of CDN or downloading assets?

Answer (score 0):

if you dont use CDN,you have much control over the assets ,as they might change/update or sometimes the url can be down :( in worst case scenario..so i suggest using local assets if there is large dependency and for small dependency ...you may use cdn. :)

use [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/getting-the-code.html) to set up `polymer js` onlocal.

Comment: I am not gonna host any. I just want to know if its a good way over ruby gems in my rails app?

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest any tutorial to add polymer js not as gem.?

Comment: added more info @KalyanDechiraju